# JSON Deserialization of nested NamedTuples in Python

Tags: python, serialization, namedtuple

JSON Serialization of nested NamedTuples is straightforward:

```
import json
from typing import NamedTuple

class A(NamedTuple):
    a: int
class B(NamedTuple):
    a: A
    b: str
s = json.dumps(B(A(42), "auie"))
print(s) # outputs the following string: "[[42], 'auie']"
```

JSON Deserialization, on the other hand, requires some work… What would be the best approach? I thought using a recursive function but I was hoping there would be a cleaner implementation…

```
def deserialize(T,l):
    for i, k in enumerate(T._field_types):
        if hasattr(T._field_types[k], "_field_types"): # I'm open to a more robust check
            l[i] = deserialize(T._field_types[k], l[i])
    return T(*l)
    
print(deserialize(B, json.loads(s))) # prints B(a=A(a=42), b='auie')
```

Comment: Is namedtuple the only thing you can use for this? The problem I see is quite a lot of ambiguity in tuples. If you could make it use `dict`s instead of tuples, you could use [dataclasses-json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/)

Comment: You're not using `namedtuple`s here, and the code you posted will give an error `name NamedTuple is not defined`!

Comment: @gimix what python version are you using?

Comment: @Jav 3.7 but I think the version doesn't matter here. You imported a type definition, which you can use for type hints, but you didn't import the `namedtuple` class and you're trying to inherit from it (all lowercase btw)

Comment: @gimix the code I posted don't give the error you mention for me… I am indeed not using namedtuple, I'm using https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: @blueteeth (sorry, missed your message) I need immutable objects... So yes, I need `NamedTuple`.

Comment: @Jav, never mind, I must have mistyped something. Sorry

Comment: @Jav What is your expected output?

Comment: The code I gave provides the (my) expected output, in case of nested `NamedTuple`s. The bounty openned by @jan-nils-ferner asks a solution to handle `Any`, `Union` and `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) which has a lot of functionalities for serializing and deserializing objects. It also allows objects to be set as immutable, see [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#faux-immutability).

Comment: For the next person checking out pydantic: It seems to fail hard with np.array

Comment: Update: Since pydantic seems to handle Union, Option, etc. well, this answer qualifies for my bounty. Congrats!